# This site can’t be reached - Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting `This site can’t be reached` and pop up window `python quit unexpectedly` error when trying to run `Django` project. It is only one particular project getting me this error any other project works perfectly.

So far I tried to all the possible solution you might think of such as running it as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, `http://0.0.0.0:8000/`, or `http://localhost:8000/`, changed `ALLOWED_HOST = ['*'] and ['127.0.0.1']` but none of them seem like work

here is my settings.py

```
    import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '**************************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

PROJECT_APPS = [    
    'users',
    'rooms',
    'core',
    'reviews',
    'reservations',
    'lists',
    'conversations',
                ]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'django_countries',"django_seed"]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + PROJECT_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"uploads")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Comment: Could you try running django but also specifying the port number when running it than try joining through that port number?

Comment: by specifying a port number you mean adding: 8000 something like that? if yes, i tried whole bunch of other numbers nothing works

Comment: If that is the case I say you try copying all the code to a knew django project to check if you accidently changed a value. Apart from that I do not know where it is wrong.

Comment: Try this solution here -https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/bt77m2/this_site_cant_be_reached_127001_refused_to/eoumac3?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 Thank you, but i tried it already still doesn't work